# Datagrip removed some variable inside procedure

Tags: datagrip

I'm using `DataGrip v 219.1.4`. I created this procedure:

```
CREATE
     PROCEDURE SP_Add_Edit_Credit_Expiration
     (IN _ID bigint, IN _User_Id bigint UNSIGNED,
      IN _Value decimal(16, 3),
      IN _Factor_Id bigint UNSIGNED,
      IN _Prefactor_id bigint UNSIGNED,
      IN _Expired_At timestamp,
      IN _Description varchar(255))
BEGIN
  IF (ISNULL(_User_Id))
  THEN
    SET _User_Id = @Auth_User;
  END IF;

  IF _ID
  THEN
    UPDATE Tb_Credit_Expirations SET value=IFNULL(_Value, value) WHERE id = _ID;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO Tb_Credit_Expirations
    SET value=_Value,
        user_id = _User_Id,
        factor_id=_Factor_Id,
        prefactor_id=_Prefactor_id,
        expired_at=_Expired_At,
        description=_Description,
        created_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    SET _ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  END IF;
END;
```

But when I want to see it :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Add_Edit_Credit_Expiration
  (IN _ID bigint,
  IN _User_Id bigint UNSIGNED,
  IN _Value decimal(16, 3),
  IN _Factor_Id bigint UNSIGNED,
  IN _Prefactor_id bigint UNSIGNED,
  IN _Expired_At timestamp,
  IN _Description varchar(255))
BEGIN
    IF (ISNULL())
    THEN
        SET  = @Auth_User;
    END IF;

    IF 
    THEN
        UPDATE Tb_Credit_Expirations SET value=IFNULL(, value) WHERE id = ;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO Tb_Credit_Expirations
        SET value=,
            user_id = ,
            factor_id=,
            prefactor_id=,
            expired_at=,
            description=,
            created_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
        SET = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END IF;
END;
```

all `IN` variables removed inside procedure. But the procedure work fine inside my php code! 
more than one my procedures it happened. I removed it and make it again but I see an incomplete procedure!

On mysql workbench software show me a complete procedure.

Comment: Then you have a display issue within datagrip, which is unfortunate, but does not seem to affect your code.

Comment: Just checked on DataGrip 2019.3 and all is fine. Can you please update DG?

Comment: Yep, It doesn't updated.